# Where should I ask general questions about my project?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a solution for a problem in my country. I decided to make a small project about it, not a startup. I need some advice about my project (which kind of server should I rent, for example). Should I ask it on Stack Overflow? My question has no code.

Answer (score 2):

These are not suitable questions for Stack Overflow (mostly becuase they do not deal with code).

In fact, there is no suitable Stack Exchange site to help with with such questions - recommendations/shopping questions are pretty much off-topic across the network (with a few notable exceptions, who have very strict requirements from such questions).

Answer (score 1):

That's kind of a shopping question, and there's no real service recommendations site.

Its one of those niches that SE doesn't really cover. I would *really* get in touch with an appropriate organisation of local geeks. There's a few posts floating around that could be of help on various sites, but with the information, or lack of it here, I'd suggest *reading up* first - chances are a lot of what you need is floating around, clearly defining the problem and working from there.